# How to replace last character on every line Notepad++

Tags: notepad++

I have lots of data like this

```
google3com/forld/umss/damo174_dfhcfg.php  
google3com/forld/umss/damo174_ffg66f.php
```

I want to replace only the latest 10 character with : `VVVVVV.htm`

So the result will be like this:

```
google3com/forld/umss/damo174_VVVVVV.htm
google3com/forld/umss/damo174_VVVVVV.htm
```

How can I do that?

Comment: Are these lines in a single file, or file names in a single directory, or what?

Comment: By using a regular expression

Comment: Please be more specific: What exactly needs to be replaced? Exactly 10 characters? Everything after `_` with varying length? What’s the replacement? `VVVVVV` doesn’t really look sensible to me. Is it really always the same?

Comment: I need last 10 characters to be replaced with "VVVVVV.htm"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Notepad++ < 6 install [RegRexPlace](http://f0dder.dcmembers.com/nppplugs/npp_plugins.zip) plugin or other plugin, that add regex search/replace functionality.

Notepad++ >= 6 have build-in regex support.

In **search** field enter `_(\d|\w){6}\.php$`

In **replace** field enter `_VVVVVV.htm`

Comment: There is no need for a plugin. Notepad++ comes with RegEx support built-in.